# How can I use my defined name of range in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some defined names in Excel's name manager. For example like these:

[image: For example these:]

I want to use them in my VBA code, but I don't know how. Could anyone here help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Range("salaries")` or `Sheet1.Range("salaries")`.